# Customize required message for GenderEnum type radio button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, required-field

I'm trying show this message "O campo sexo é obrigatório" when the guest doesn't check the Gender radio, but all that I get is show: "The Model field is required."

Code is here:

```
// GenderEnum.cs
namespace Diorama.Site.Models
{
    public enum GenderEnum
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }
}

// RegisterViewModel.cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo sexo é obrigatório")]
[Name("Moça ou rapaz?")]
public GenderEnum Gender { get; set; }

public static void Map()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<RegisterViewModel, User>()
        .ForMember(u => u.Gender,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(r => r.Gender.ToString()[0]));
    Mapper.CreateMap<User, RegisterViewModel>()
        .ForMember(r => r.Gender,
                    o => o.MapFrom(u =>
                                    u.Gender.ToLower() == "M"
                                        ? GenderEnum.Male
                                        : GenderEnum.Female));
}

//_RegisterForm.cshtml
<div class="controls">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, ""
                                    , new { @class = "help-block" })
</div>
```

Comment: are you shure this error is about the gender field?

Comment: Sure, when the page is rendered I can see this message in the code: 
<label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" value="Female" name="Gender" id="Gender" data-val-required="The Model field is required." data-val="true"> Moça</label>
<label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" value="Male" name="Gender" id="Gender"> Rapaz</label>
    <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Gender" class="field-validation-valid help-block"></span>

Comment: the fields are rendered by EditorTemplate:

`@ModelType GenderEnum
 
<label class="radio inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) Model, GenderEnum.Female) Moça</label>
<label class="radio inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) Model, GenderEnum.Male) Rapaz</label>`

Does it help?